# Attach JS to tableselect checkboxes?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

Using the Drupal 7 tableselect form field, is there a way to attach javascript events to the checkboxes?

I am trying to build a custom pricing table that lets you add different options, which modifies the displayed total. When checking off an option, I need to pass the value through AJAX and return a new total price. Not sure though how to attach events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '#ajax' property handling of the tableselect element is broken at the moment. The approach shown by mrryanjohnston *should* work in theory, but I can confirm Kevins observation that it does not do so for checkboxes ('#multiple' = true). It does work for radio buttons, though ('#multiple' = false). The issue [is reported as a bug](http://drupal.org/node/1458824) in the meantime.

To me this seems to be just an oversight - looking at [`form_process_tableselect()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_process_tableselect/7) shows that the line which passes the '#ajax' property on to the created child elements is only present in the 'radios' related `else` part of the if clause, but absent for the default checkbox creation part. Adding the line there fixes the problem on first sight - not sure if it has some negative effects and was left out on purpose, but I doubt that.

As a workaround to avoid patching core, you can register an additional `#process` callback, to be invoked after the default one:

```
$form['some_tableselect'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => array('one', 'two'),
  '#options' => your_module_function_creating_options(),
  // Kludge/workaround for broken #ajax handling for checkboxes,
  // register an additional process callback:
  '#process' => array('form_process_tableselect', 'your_module_tableselect_process_callback'),
);
```

Then in your new callback, you add the ajax property to the created checkboxes directly:

```
function your_module_tableselect_process_callback($form_element) {
  foreach (element_children($form_element) as $child_key) {
    if ('checkbox' == $form_element[$child_key]['#type']) {
      // Add ajax behavior as desired
      $form_element[$child_key]['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'your_module_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'some-wrapper-id',
      );
    }
  }

  return $form_element;
}
```

Note that this only covers the individual checkboxes per line - the 'select all' checkbox in the header gets added via JavaScript later on, and can not be 'fixed' like this :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is quite doable with the #ajax key in a renderable array. From http://drupal.org/node/752056:

```
<?php
/**
 * AJAX-enabled select element causes replacement of a set of checkboxes
 * based on the selection.
 */
function ajax_example_autocheckboxes($form, &$form_state) {

  $default = !empty($form_state['values']['howmany']) ? $form_state['values']['howmany'] : 1;

  $form['howmany_select'] = array(
    '#title' => t('How many checkboxes do you want?'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 4 => 4),
    '#default_value' => $default,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'checkboxes-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),

  );


  $form['checkboxes_fieldset'] = array(
    '#title' => t("Generated Checkboxes"),
    // The prefix/suffix provide the div that we're replacing, named by
    // #ajax['wrapper'] above.
    '#prefix' => '<div id="checkboxes-div">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('This is where we get automatically generated checkboxes'),
  );

  // Complete example below!
```

Basically, define what function is going to be triggered by what action (in this case, a checkbox toggle). With the above code, define a function such that its signature is `ajax_example_autocheckboxes_callback`. Voila.

Comment: This works for common fields like select, but tableselect does not seem to do anything, even though its listed as supporting the #ajax property.

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin try this

```
function a_form($form, &$formstate){
  $header = array
  (
    'name' => 'name',
    'surname' => 'surname',
    'citizen_id' => 'citizen id',
  );

  $options['1'] = array(
    'name' => '1name',
    'surname' => '1surname',
    'citizen_id' => '1citi',
  );

  $options['2'] = array(
    'name' => '2name',
    'surname' => '2surname',
    'citizen_id' => '2citi',
  );

  $form['tableselect_field'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#multiple' => FALSE,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'an_example_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'a-div',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
  );

  $form['ajax_div'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="a-div">',
    '#markup' => date('y-m-d h:i:s'),
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}

function an_example_callback($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['ajax_div'];
}
```

Comment: This is what I have for my tableselect, but no ajax fires (checking Firebug)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [new patch](http://drupal.org/node/1458824) for ajax on tableselect checkboxes.